# How to stop a second xsession on display :1

Tags: x-server

All the Google results give information about how to start a second xserver, or recommend stopping the display manager, However I don't wish to close all my displays, just the non-primary ones, specifically the one started on display :1.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most natural way would be to kill the session manager process for that session. Killing the session manager ends the session.

On Linux, you can use `ps xeww | grep DISPLAY=:1` to list processes that have `DISPLAY=:1` in their environment. Many other Unix variants have a way to do this, but the options to `ps` vary. Beware that this can return false positives that happen to have `DISPLAY=:1` somewhere in the output (such as the grep command itself, which may or may not appear depending on the speed at which the parts of the pipeline are started).

To have an easier time locating the session manager, use `ps xewwf | grep DISPLAY=:1 | less`. The session manager will be one of those whose parent isn't listed.

Alternatively, look for the X server. In practice, each display is controlled by a separate X server process. `fuser /tmp/.X11-unix/X1` lists the X server controlling display `:1`; pass the `-k` option to kill the process. You'll need to be root to do that.